# BASH: Comparing the Permissions of a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I tried to compare the premission of two files in Bash by the following code:

```
!#/bin/bash
echo "Enter the first file name: "
read first
echo "Enter the second file name: "
read second
fileperm=$(stat -c '%A' "$first")
filepermi=$(stat -c '%A' "$second")

if [ "$fileperm" = "$filepermi" ]; then
        echo $(stat -c '%A' "$fileperm") 
fi
```

But it gives me error on the if following are the errors:

> ***stat: invalid option -- 'r'  Try 'stat --help' for more information.***

Comment: Should not be it `#!/bin/bash` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect this line to do?

```
echo $(stat -c '%A' "$fileperm")
```

For most inputs to your script, `$fileperm` is going to be something like `-rw-r--r--`, which explains the error message you're getting.

Comment: I just want to print the permission, if they are equal.

Comment: Then don't call `stat` again. Just `echo $fileperm` should do it.

Comment: It worked thanks, a tick is just coming towards you :)